# how to find last alphabet in string which is combination of number and character in java

Tags: java

I have the following string I want to `spilts` string based on last alphabets in string
for e.g consider

```
 String str =  '02191204E8DA4459.jpg' how to extract 4459 from str ?
```

i try following code but that but in above string alphabets are not constant
actullally i want to add images sequeunce in database for e.g

```
'02191204E8DA4459.jpg' to '02191204E8DA4465.jpg' i.e 6 images

  String sec1 = null, sec2 = null, result = null, initfilename = null;
    int lowerlimit, upperlimit;
    String realimg1, realimg2;
    String str1 = "120550DA121.jpg"; // here  DA is constant 
    String str2 = "120550DA130.jpg"; //
    String[] parts1;
    String[] parts2;
    realimg1 = str1.substring(0, str1.length() - 4); // remove .jpg from image name
    realimg2 = str2.substring(0, str2.length() - 4); //
    if (realimg1.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {             // checking whether imagename has alphabets 
        parts1 = realimg1.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"); // It matches positions between a number and not-a-number (in any order).
        parts2 = realimg2.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"); // It matches positions between a number and not-a-number (in any order).

        sec1 = parts1[0];
        sec2 = parts1[1];

        result = sec1.concat(sec2);

        lowerlimit = Integer.parseInt(parts1[parts1.length - 1]);
        upperlimit = Integer.parseInt(parts2[parts2.length - 1]);

        for (int j = lowerlimit; j <= upperlimit; j++) {
            initfilename = result + j + ".jpg";
            System.out.println(initfilename);
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = Integer.parseInt(realimg1); j <= Integer.parseInt(realimg2); j++) {
            initfilename = j + ".jpg";
            System.out.println(initfilename);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe that if you actually think about your problem, you can solve it without the assistance of the SO community. Just atleast try something..

Comment: yes right i tried to solve but i stuck somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest way, since it wouldn't work for strings not preceded by non-digits:

```
String str = "02191204E8DA4459.jpg";
String lastNumber = str.replaceAll("^.*[^0-9](\\d+).*?$", "$1");
System.out.println(lastNumber);
```

Comment: thanks for ans but how to find first part then i.e 02191204E8DA ?

Comment: For the first part, try with: "^(.*[^0-9])(\\d+).*?$"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex:

```
String str =  "02191204E8DA4459.jpg";
if(str.matches(".*\\d{4}\\.jpg")) {
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".*(\\d{4})\\.jpg", "$1"));
}
```

- `str.matches(".*\\d{4}\\.jpg")` returns `true` if the string ends with 4 digits and .jpg
- `str.replaceAll(".*(\\d{4})\\.jpg", "$1")` returns a new string which contains the 4 digits you are looking for

---

If you don't know how many digits you will have, you can replace your regex with this one:

```
.*(\\d+)\\.jpg
```

Comment: There won't always be 4 letters at the end, I think.

Comment: @MCL Yeah, totally forgot to escape the dot, I updated the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could split on non-digits and extract the last element of the resulting array:

```
String str = "02191204E8DA4459.jpg";

String[] split = str.split("\\D+");
System.out.println(split[split.length - 1]);
```

```
4459
```